# How many boxes can be painted while respecting this restriction?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

We have 30 boxes in a line: $x_1,x_2,...,x_{30}$. Some of them we can color in red. The rule is that if $x_k$ is colored red then $x_{k+2}$ can't be colored red and vice versa. What is the maximum number of boxes that can be colored red then.

I've tried constructing some cases. It seems kind of obvious that it's 16 by just putting a pair of colored boxes first, skip 2 boxes, color 2 boxes, skip 2 boxes, etc. until 29 and 30 are red. Not sure how to prove that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partite $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{30}$ into $14$ pairs and $2$ singletons:

- pairs: $\{ x_{4k+1}, x_{4k+3} \}, \{ x_{4k+2}, x_{4k+4} \}$ for $0 \le k \le 6$.
- singletons: $\{ x_{29} \}$ and $\{ x_{30} \}$.

Since each group can hold at most $1$ red boxes, at most $16 = 14 + 2$ boxes can be painted in red.

Comment: really concise and cool solution

Answer (score 2):

You have found a way to paint $16$. Now you have to prove that painting $17$ is impossible.

For that, suppose that $17$ boxes are painted. Let be $k$ the number of painted boxes strictly afer the $28$th (yes, $k$ can be $0$, $1$ or $2$). Than means that $17-k$ of the $28$ first boxes are painted. For every painted box from $1$ to $28$, there are another unpainted box, namely the box that is two places to the right. So at least $17-k$ boxes are unpainted. Obviously, the set $P$ of the painted boxes and the set $U$ of the unpainted ones are disjoint. That means that
$$30\geq\#P+\#U\geq 17-k+17-k$$
or
$$k\geq 4$$
clearly a contradiction.

Comment: This is cool. One thing: why is 17-k boxes (or is it at least 17-k unpainted boxes?) painted?

Comment: I find this completely incomprehensible. Why $27$? How do you get from $\geq 17-k$ painted boxes to (exactly?) $17-p$ _unpainted_ boxes? Where is the precise restriction on painting used at all (except to get $k\neq3$)?

Comment: I meant $28th$ instead of $27th$, sorry...

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions (just replace "Why $27$" by "Why $28$"). There seems to be just nothing that relates these numbers with each other, or with the problem.

Comment: After the $28th$ box there are exactly two boxes. These two boxes are special, in the sense that if you paint them, this does not prevent that any other box can be painted. If $k$ of these two boxes are painted, since there are $17$ painted boxes, there are $17-k$ painted boxes from the $1$st to the $28$th.

Comment: This is also a cool solution

Comment: OK, after the edit the words are there to make the argument understandable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but the general formula for $n$ boxes is:

$$\lceil\frac{n}{4}\rceil+\lceil\frac{n-1}{4}\rceil$$

Perhaps you can prove it by induction...

Answer (score 2):

Since the painting restriction always involves boxes with the same parity, one can consider odd and even indexed boxes separately; two rows of $15$ boxes each. Within each row no two adjacent boxes can be painted, so every painted box, except possibly the last one in its row, is followed in its row by at least one unpainted box (of the same parity) and no unpainted box is accounted for more than once this way. Therefore at most $8$ boxes in each row can be painted, or $16$ in all.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense